# Docker(file) .net core angular 7 wdm failed to compile because of node sass. (SPA Middleware included)

Tags: angular, docker, .net-core, node-sass

Im trying to run an angular .NET Core app via spa middleware in a docker container.  When I create a new angular app in Visual Studio 2017 Pro and add docker support it initially fails because I need NPM installed. So I added the boiler plate code to install NodeJs I ripped from the net in my dockerfile:

(BTW: I did ng new ClientApp after removing the angular 5 one to have version 7 with css styles)

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
# Setup NodeJs
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
# End setup
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
# Setup NodeJs
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
# End setup
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["A7NCDS/A7NCDS.csproj", "A7NCDS/"]
RUN dotnet restore "A7NCDS/A7NCDS.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/A7NCDS"
RUN dotnet build "A7NCDS.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "A7NCDS.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "A7NCDS.dll"]
```

When I run this in docker it all works fine! But now when I remove my ClientApp and do ng new ClientApp with SCSS support instead of CSS I get this error:

```
Error: Missing binding /app/ClientApp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-67/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 11.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Windows 64-bit with Node.js 11.x
```

So I did some googleFU and ended up placing npm rebuild node-sass in my Dockerfile somewhere which I lost now which just gave me the vague error without details: WDM failed to compile.

How do I make it work? Im so stuck right now. I did not make any changes to .csproj files or startup.cs. Im considering removing SCSS/SASS altogether but this is not a realistic pragmatic solution. (What if some other library becomes platform specific altogether?)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of nodejs and npm are you using? Did you tried to rebuild with 
 `npm rebuild node-sass` from your project folder? Try also to remove npm cache and reinstall node modules again.
Also try to install sass globally,

```
npm install -g sass
```

docker file example

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils
RUN apt-get install -y sudo
RUN apt-get install -y curl && apt-get install -y ssh
RUN apt-get install -y libfontconfig && apt-get install -y git
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
COPY apache.pem /
COPY package.json /
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4200
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Where do I place these commands? In my docker file or in the csproj file or in the startup.cs? How would i find out which version it is i am using? Its downloading some node 11.x version for as far I can see. The problem is im on windows and try to run in a linux container. Im a bit clueless on where the npm commands get run because when app gets published in docker file the csproy commands get ran right? So why would it even come up with windows bindings?

Comment: I added npm rebuild node-sass to csproj and now its missing a package.json file. This is getting weirder by the minute. I dont understand why it workes out of the box when not using sass scss!

Comment: locally with 'node -v' you can check nodejs version. If it worked with angular 5 and you upgraded to angular 7, then it has something probably with nodejs version. required version of node for angular 7 is 8.9 and higher. Sorry I can't help you more because I am not using VS2017.

Comment: Your commands should be in your docker file. I will post example docker file that I am using in my projects. Basically you prepare image, download nodejs, copy package.json and run npm install

Comment: Hey it worked with angular 7 with css by the way. In docker. Only thing i added in dockerfile was nodejs install on the two images!